# wrong conversion done in c# for Mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

i have the code in c#

```
   string date = reader["date"].ToString();
```

and got error that

> Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

when i convert them to string then why it's trying to convert them to datetime. well the value they create error is  `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573153/how-to-get-a-date-from-mysql-database-to-c-sharp-datetime-object

have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `0000-00-00 00:00:00` is not valid .Net DateTime ([minimum value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) is  00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001)

Add this to the connection string :

`Allow Zero Datetime=true` and `Convert Zero Datetime=true`

Answer (score 0):

Then you should do some changes like follows in your connection string

```
Allow Zero Datetime=true
```

To know why you should do like that see this [conversation](http://forums.asp.net/t/1259101.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the database call is returning a `MySqlDateTime` class object.
Try the following code:

```
MySqlDateTime mysqlDate = reader["date"];
DateTime date = mysqlDate.GetDateTime();
string date = date.ToString();
```